# How to work (get, set) with query string in a url using react or Gatsby (whitout window || document)

Tags: reactjs, url, gatsby, query-string, querystringparameter

How to get or set the query string using React or Gatsby (without using document or window objects):

```
https://link.com/?color=#fff&theme=light
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this module for `react`:
https://github.com/pbeshai/use-query-params

for `gatsby`, you can use this plugin :
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-use-query-params/
it'll wrap your app with `QueryParamProvider`